# React / React-DOM package dependency conflict

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, package.json

I've been running into this error message every time I try to run *npm update*:

:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-website@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0" from @material-ui/core@4.11.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   react-dom@"^17.0.1" from the root project
```

I get this error message in the console when I try to run *npm install react-parallax*:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-website@0.1.0
        
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"16.x.x" from react-parallax@3.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-parallax
npm ERR!     react-parallax@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   react-dom@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Here is my current package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js",
      "!src/index.js"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried deleting my node_modules folder, npm installing but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I haven't spent a lot of time dealing with these types of bugs to understanding what exactly the console is requesting me to fix is a little alien to me. What exactly is the problem, how do I fix it, and how to I stop this from happening in the future?

Comment: In short: versions of `react` and `react-dom` must match.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Can you try running it with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. I think you are using the latest Beta release of npm v7.

It's mentioned in the Error message as well.

```
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

You can check more about the beta release [here](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major)

Answer (score 3):

You can use npm install --legacy-peer-deps which will automatically resolve all the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `npm install --force` if only [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64842124/5954248) is not working.

**Waning** - *NOT A GOOD PRACTICE*

Answer (score 0):

You just need to rerun this command until it gets verified.
**npx cypress open**

Answer (score 0):

Check if your react and react-dom versions are compatible:

https://www.npmpeer.dev/packages/react-dom/compatibility

I do not recommend using:

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Even if you locally fix your problem with it, it will reveal when somebody will want to install deps using `npm i`. This problem can appear for example, in your CI where you probably use simple `npm i` wihtout flags.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue which is due to incompatibility of versions like node-sass version 4 is not compatible with node version 16. This can be achieved by downgrading node version to 14 and then use nvm use [node-version].
For downloading multiple node versions,
visit this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nvm-for-windows-how-to-download-and-install-node-version-manager-in-windows-10/#followthestepsbelowtodownloadnvmwindows)