# NPM Next / React package dependency conflict

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I know this is related to [React / React-DOM package dependency conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842060/react-react-dom-package-dependency-conflict), but the solutions which I can find there don't really help me.

When installing/updating a dependency or when deploying my Next.js app to Vercel, I get some of the following errors:

```bash
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: use-ackee@3.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (next, react-dom, react-helmet, react-side-effect, styled-jsx)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from use-ackee@3.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/use-ackee
npm ERR!   use-ackee@"^3.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0" from use-ackee@3.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/use-ackee
npm ERR!     use-ackee@"^3.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "next": "^13.1.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "use-ackee": "^3.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

I'm fully aware that I can just use `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` and everything works fine, but this seems like it is not really stable.

What is the exact problem I'm dealing with here? What can I do to resolve those conflicts?

Comment: The exact problem is **in the error**: `use-ackee@^3.0.1` works with `react@^17.0.0`, and you're using `react@^18.2.0`. So what you can do to resolve, given the former has no newer version, is downgrade React.

Comment: Seems like you have to wait for https://github.com/electerious/use-ackee/pull/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check the peer dependencies of `use-ackee@3.0.1` package.

```
$ npm view use-ackee@3.0.1 peerDependencies
{ react: '^17.0.0' }
```

As you can see, the `use-ackee` package demands the `react` package as its peer dependency with version `^17.0.0`. But in your project, the installed `react` version is `^18.2.0`. That's why you got the warning.

So one safe solution is to downgrade the `react` package to `^17.0.0`.

```
$ npm i react@^17.0.0 react-dom@^17.0.0 -S
```

Usually, please be careful to run the `npm install <package>` with the `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps` option, it will cause potentially broken. Instead, we should fix the version compatibility issues between dependent packages.

It also mentioned [here#legacy-peer-deps](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps)

> Use of `legacy-peer-deps` is not recommended, as it will not enforce the `peerDependencies` contract that meta-dependencies may rely on.

But you can use the `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` options if you confirm the runtime code is compatible in advance. Let's see the `use-ackee@3.0.1` package's [source code](https://github.com/electerious/use-ackee/blob/v3.0.1/src/index.js)

```js
const { useMemo, useEffect } = require('react')
const ackeeTracker = require('ackee-tracker')

const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined'

/**
 * Use Ackee in React.
 * Creates an instance once and a new record every time the pathname changes.
 * Safely no-ops during server-side rendering.
 * @param {?String} pathname - Current path.
 * @param {Object} environment - Object containing the URL of the Ackee server and the domain id.
 * @param {?Object} options - Ackee options.
 */
const useAckee = function(pathname, environment, options = {}) {
    const instance = useMemo(() => {
        if (isBrowser === false) return

        return ackeeTracker.create(environment.server, options)
    }, [ environment.server, options.detailed, options.ignoreLocalhost, options.ignoreOwnVisits ])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (instance == null) {
            console.warn('Skipped record creation because useAckee has been called in a non-browser environment')
            return
        }

        const hasPathname = (
            pathname != null &&
            pathname !== ''
        )

        if (hasPathname === false) {
            console.warn('Skipped record creation because useAckee has been called without pathname')
            return
        }

        const attributes = ackeeTracker.attributes(options.detailed)
        const url = new URL(pathname, location)

        return instance.record(environment.domainId, {
            ...attributes,
            siteLocation: url.href,
        }).stop
    }, [ instance, pathname, environment.domainId ])
}

module.exports = useAckee
module.exports.useAckee = useAckee
```

It only uses the `useMemo` and `useEffect` hooks from the `react` package. Those hooks' behavior has no change in `React 18.x`. That's why you can ignore peer dependency and use the version installed(`React 18.x`) in your project.